# How i make the same table model (without the words contents) in react native/expo as my picture example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

how I make the same table model **(i need the same table without the contents)** in react-native/expo as my picture examples?
I try so many things but its doesn't work for me and i need some help with that.
here you can see my example **the first picture** and I want to transfer it to the example as the second picture.

> **this is the example table that i have now:**

[image]

> **this is the example table that i want :**

[image]

> this is my code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    ActivityIndicator,
    Platform,
    FlatList,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Dimensions
} from "react-native";
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from "react-navigation-header-buttons";
import HeaderButton from "../components/HeaderButton";
import axios from "axios";
import { Card } from "react-native-elements";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";



const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
export default class MainScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: [] };
    }

    getData = () => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true, data: [] })
        axios.get("https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums ")
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    data: res.data
                });
                console.log(res.data);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({ getData: this.getData });
        this.getData()
    }

    renderItem(item) {
        const { title, artist} = item.item;
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Settings")}
            >
                 <View style={styles.itemView}>
                <View style={styles.itemInfo}>
                    <Text style={styles.name}>
                        {title+ ' ' + artist}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.vertical} numberOfLines={1}>{artist} |</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <View style={{ flex:0,paddingTop: 300 }}>
                    <Text style={{ alignSelf: "center", fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 20 }}>loading data...</Text>
                    <ActivityIndicator size={'large'} color={'#08cbfc'} />
                </View>
            );
        }
        return (
            <>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <FlatList
                        data={this.state.data}
                        renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
                        keyExtractor={(_, index) => String(index)}
                    />
                    {/* <Text>{this.state.data.length !== 0 ? this.state.data.length : "NO DATA FOUND" }</Text> */}
                </View>

                <View style={styles.bottomMainContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.bottomView} >
                        <Text style={styles.bottomTextStyle}>סה"כ: {this.state.data.length} רשומות</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 0,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        // backgroundColor:'pink'


    },
    itemView: {
        flex: 1,
        width,
        borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        paddingHorizontal: 12,
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    imgContainer: {
        // flex: 0,
        // borderColor: 'black',
        // borderWidth: 1.5,
        // height: 60,
        // width: 60,
        // alignItems: 'center',
        // justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    itemInfo: {
        flex: 1,
        marginHorizontal: 10,
        // backgroundColor:'pink'
    },
    name: {
        //fontFamily: 'Verdana',
        fontSize: 18,
        color: '#ff0000',
        textAlign: 'left',
    },
    vertical: {
        fontSize: 18,
    }
```

Comment: you can hardcode it with Views and Text fields but if its data that comes from an API or an Array then check out the FlatList component from React Native.

Comment: i want just the model ...the colors and the lines

Comment: show me nice way to make it